# Add days to current date in groovy

Tags: groovy

I am trying to get the current date and change the format and add 30 days to it,  i tried the following in groovy :

```
def date = new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd")
def laterdate = date + 30
log.info laterdate
```

I get the output as (formatting looks good)

```
Mon Jul 24 12:24:04 MST 2017:INFO:2017-07-2430
```

can someone please advise where i am doing wrong

Comment: When you use `format`  the `Date` object gets turned into a string.

Comment: close the question before someone votes this down

Answer (score 27):

To add days:

```
Date date = new Date().plus(30)
```

To Substract days:

```
Date date = new Date().plus(-30)
```

Comment: It would make a lot more sense to use `minus(30)` rather than `plus(-30)`

Comment: if you are using grails version > 3.1.11 then better check https://stackoverflow.com/a/65344838/4293260

Answer (score 4):

```
def today = new Date()
def nextMonth = today + 30
log.info today.format("yyyy-MM-dd")
log.info nextMonth.format("yyyy-MM-dd")
```