# Date.plus not working in 2.5.4 Groovy Runtime, what is the alternative?

Tags: java, date, groovy

We want to add days to the current date and format it in a specific way. This was solved in Groovy 2.4.13 and the following date manipulation works fine:

```
​today = new Date()+90;today.format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S');
```

Result: 2019-12-02 08:07:15.294

In Groovy 2.5.4 the same expression throws this exception:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
>   java.util.Date.plus() is applicable for argument types: (Integer)
>   values: [90] Possible solutions: parse(java.lang.String),
>   split(groovy.lang.Closure), use([Ljava.lang.Object;),
>   is(java.lang.Object), wait(), clone()     at
>   Script1.run(Script1.groovy:3)

I was able to reproduce this behaviour in "Groovy sandboxes" online:

Working fine here: [groovy-playground](https://groovy-playground.appspot.com/) (Version 2.4.1.5)
Failing here: [groovyconsole](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/) (Version 2.5.7)

What is the working alternative in this case? I have read about a new Date API, but couldn't find the details about how to use it, with date manipulation (+ 90 days for example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Ole V.V.'s recommendations to use the new Date/Time API. Here is how you would write his Java sample in a more Groovy style.

```
// you can assemble aggregate types by left shifting the aggregates
// I'm not endorsing this approach, necessarily, just pointing it out as an alternative 
ZonedDateTime now = LocalDate.now() << LocalTime.now() << ZoneId.of('Africa/Bamako')

// the plus operator is overloaded
ZonedDateTime in90Days = now + 90

// you can pass a String to format without needed a full DateTimeFormatter instance
println in90Days.format('uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S')
```

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [TimeCategory](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/time/TimeCategory.html)

```
import groovy.time.TimeCategory
def theDate = use(TimeCategory){new Date() + 90.days}.format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S')
```

Comment: I'd recommend this approach to anyone who needs to keep using the java.util.Date object.

Comment: This is the only real answer to the question. Yes, `java.time` and/or Joda-Time are much better for Date/Time programming needs, but not everyone has the opportunity to switch

Answer (score 2):

While Groovy adds some further support for the old Java `Date` class, I still believe that you should not use it. It was always poorly designed and is now long outdated. Instead use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. I am sorry that I will have to trust you to translate from Java code.

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
    ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Africa/Bamako"));
    ZonedDateTime in90Days = now.plusDays(90);
    System.out.println(in90Days.format(formatter));
```

Output when running just now was:

> 2020-01-01 08:37:13.3

Please substitute your desired time zone if it didn’t happen to be Africa/Bamako.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Answer (score 1):

For Groovy 2.5 and above, you can get the same behavior as in Groovy 2.4 by adding the `groovy-dateutil` module to your classpath. It became an optional module in Groovy 2.5 since many folks are using the now preferred `java.time` classes. Groovy's extension methods for the new classes are in the `groovy-datetime` module which is referenced in the `groovy-all` POM.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Calendar to achieve that

```
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 90);
    Date date = cal.getTime();
```

All steps must be separate and not in a single line.